# How can I copy my all java codes from windows workspace and use it in linux eclipse workspace

Tags: java, linux, windows, eclipse, ubuntu

I have currently switched to Ubuntu and want to continue using it. So,I want to copy all my codes that was in windows workspace to Ubuntu's eclipse workspace so that I can use that code whenever required. So I copied all codes and pasted in ubuntu's eclipse workspace but facing problem that when I open eclipse in ubuntu,it is still empty. It is not recognizing any of the copied projects. How can I use it in Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can follow the below steps.

a. Right click on your project and click **export**.

b. select **file system** and save in desktop or u r preferred loc.

c. In Linux eclipse menu click **file** and select **import** option.

d. select **existing projects in to workspace** and give the project path.

Answer (score 1):

You need to import the projects into Eclipse, regardless of whether you pasted the files into the work space. Go to File>Import, choose the type of project it is that you want to import, and follow the prompts.

[Here is a simple tutorial.](http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftasks-importproject.htm)

Also, maybe look into using version control such as git. Here are some resources on that. I really like TortoiseGit.

[Git for Beginners](https://product.hubspot.com/blog/git-and-github-tutorial-for-beginners)

[TortoiseGit](https://tortoisegit.org/)

Comment: Thanks.It worked. But should I do it for all project one by one as there is no "select all" option.

Comment: @PatelParth If all of your projects exist in the same directory, you should be able to do a File -> Import... -> Existing Projects into workspace and select the directory where all of the projects are located.

Answer (score 0):

1. *Paste* your Java folder/directory that contain the source code in your home folder.
2. *Create* a new project in Eclipse, or simply *use an existing project.*
3. *Right-click* on the project tag. Or simply click on **File** and then **Import**.
4. *Select Import*, and follow up until you reach your saved Java folder/directory with the source code.